# Titanium 5 - Fetching Collection instance causes crash in Android

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I made an app using Titanium SDK 3.X about a year ago. Everything was fine in both iOS and Android. Now, I'm trying to add a new functionality. I installed SDK 5. I opened the app in Appcelerator Studio and the app works fine in iOS. However, it doesn't work in Android. I investigated and **the problem was caused by the fetching from the collection instance**. When I erased the fetching `$.books.fetch()`, the app didn't crash. But if i don't, it crashes the app, then the app restarts. Unfortunately, there weren't any error logs from the Phone or in the Console (in Appcelerator Studio).

The View:

```
<Alloy>
<Collection src="books" instance="true" id="books" />
    <Window id="winFilterByName" title="Find By Name" >
        <TableView id="allBookList" dataCollection="$.books" dataTransform="transformFunction" dataFilter="filterFunction" zIndex="0" filterAttribute="rowFilter" top="0" >

         ...
        </TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

The controller:

```
/* Fetch the Collections
 * ********************************************************* */
  Alloy.Collections.bookmarks.fetch();
  $.books.fetch(); //<-- This caused the problem...
```

in `alloy.js`, I do the line of code below. So on app-startup, It's accessible for `fetch()`.

```
Alloy.Collections.bookmarks = Alloy.createCollection('bookmarks');
```

I can't find any resources how to fix this. The resources that I can find via Google is still from SDK 3.X and I've done exactly that. But it crashes in the app.

The Android version on the Phone is 5.1.1.

**UPDATE**

This is a recurring error in the Console:

```
[ERROR] :  art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 36 byte allocation with 32 free bytes and 32B until OOM"
```

And then eventually it gets followed by this block of errors

```
[ERROR] :  art: "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
[ERROR] :  art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x76818e48 self=0xb873f410
[ERROR] :  art:   | sysTid=7647 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6efcbec
[ERROR] :  art:   | state=R schedstat=( 3091837554 376855300 3730 ) utm=266 stm=43 core=0 HZ=100
[ERROR] :  art:   | stack=0xbe523000-0xbe525000 stackSize=8MB
[ERROR] :  art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.util.PathParser$PathDataNode.nodesToPath(PathParser.java:283)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPath.toPath(VectorDrawable.java:1262)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPathRenderer.drawPath(VectorDrawable.java:947)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPathRenderer.drawGroupTree(VectorDrawable.java:928)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPathRenderer.drawGroupTree(VectorDrawable.java:924)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPathRenderer.draw(VectorDrawable.java:935)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.draw(VectorDrawable.java:271)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.draw(AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:178)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.widget.ProgressBar.drawTrack(ProgressBar.java:1677)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.widget.ProgressBar.onDraw(ProgressBar.java:1644)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15292)
[ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14219)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14241)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3392)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3371)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14179)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14241)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3392)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3371)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14179)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14241)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3392)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3371)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14179)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14241)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3392)
 [ERROR] :  art:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3371)
 ...
```

Comment: I see you use a filter function and a transform function. Try to cut those out and see if it still works. If it does, that is the problem. Try to debug from there

Comment: Hi Rene Pot, I did used your suggestion to debug. I took out the `transform function` and the `filter function`. The app still crashes and restarts. I also took out the `filterAttribute` but the app still crashes and restarts.